# Load custom knowledge-graph data to pytorch geometric

Tags: python, pytorch, knowledge-graph, pytorch-geometric

I am new to PyTorch geometric and want to know how we can load our own knowledge-graph dataset into PyTorch geometric DataLoader. I have my data in the CSV file which looks like for example:[image]

Dataset consists of 1000's of such triples
I went through PyTorch documentation but couldn't understand how this kind of data can be used with Pytorch geometric.
I was using this data earlier with ampligraph to do link prediction and thought of giving it try with GNN (PyTorch geometric).
Any help on this!!